# Looking for the Livescribe SDK, and/or ways to hack the Pulse Smartpen

Tags: sdk, livescribe

I'm looking for an old copy of the Livescribe SDK.  Livescribe have discontinued their developer program, and I've searched far and wide for it, only finding others asking for the same:
http://www.kellbot.com/2011/06/livescribe-developer-community-huge-f-you/

I'm envisioning new ways the smartpen could be extended with extra functionality (bluetooth / wifi) for extra scenarios (it could do your expenses automatically, or work with musical staff / stave paper).

I'm trying to get as close to working prototypes as possible, and interested in anyone who is developing with Anoto dot paper, or any other smartpen manufacturer.

Comment: Well I'll add an update  
I've searched high and low for a copy of the original livescribe developer SDK, but to no avail.  
  
The options that I know of are as follows:  
1. Get the new Sky wifi smartpen - I don't know if the SDK is out yet, but they have promised to release one for this pen  
2. Use the Anoto SDK.  this only works on windows according to the guys at Ars Electronica lab, who used it to make  
[link](http://www.aec.at/press/en/2012/07/24/voyage-of-discovery/)  
3. what I did - order the unlined journals, take pages out and print onto them again!

Comment: This isn't really a question about programming so Stack Overflow probably isn't the ideal place to get help. Maybe the best idea would be to find someone who has already developed software using the SDK and ask them -- SO probably isn't the ideal place to get help with that though.

Comment: The rapid share link is empty. Does anyone else have a copy of the SDK to share?

Comment: I second English Grad. Any luck to share the SDK somehow?

Comment: I cannot find it anywhere - link is not working. Can anybody send it? I can pay for it if needed. vova@77xy.net

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an SDK for Livescribe, but you might want to take a look at this link: [livescribe.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1/kw/sdk](https://livescribe.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1/kw/sdk)

> Livescribe has developed an SDK for Apple iOS 7 (or later) that
>   enables the Livescribe 3 smartpen to connect directly to a tablet or
>   smartphone using Bluetooth® LE (Low Energy) 4.0+. With the Livescribe
>   3 SDK, specific partner developers will be able to quickly and easily
>   add support for the Livescribe 3 smartpen and enhance their
>   note-taking, drawing, annotation, and collaboration applications.  For
>   an example of the SDK working in a developer app, please see their
>   blog post on Outline/Outline+ . If you would like to get involved with
>   the Livescribe SDK, please email developer@livescribe.com.

Comment: @Rhymold I copied the text from the website, but the link to the blog post actually doesn't exist. What else should I add?